# postgres full text search like operator

Tags: postgresql

what is the query to use to search for text that matches the like operator.

I am asking about full text search query, which is of the form

```
 SELECT * FROM eventlogging WHERE description_tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('mess');
```

I want results with "message" as well but right not it does not return anything

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I read the [description in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES) correctly, you'll need to use `to_tsquery()` instead of plainto_tsquery together with a wildcard to allow prefix matching:

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventlogging 
WHERE description_tsv @@ to_tsquery('mess:*');
```

Comment: is there anything for suffix matching as well

Answer (score -7):

You can use `LIKE` for exact case matches or `ILIKE` for case insensitive. Use the `%` as your wildcard.

This will match anything with 'SomeThing' in it (case sensitive).

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%SomeThing%'
```

This will match anything ending with "ing" (case insensitive).

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name ILIKE '%ing'
```

Comment: I am asking about full text search query, which is of the form SELECT * FROM events WHERE description_tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('mess*');   I want results with message as well but right not it does not return anything