# "like" query on postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have this method that does a fuzzy search for a name on a sqlite3 database, meaning that if you search the letter "j" it will return any entry that has a "j" anywhere: "John" and "Vijay" would both match. However, when I push the rails app to Heroku, the application uses postgres, and the query's no longer working. According to this SO answer [postgres full text search like operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588717/postgres-full-text-search-like-operator), postgres does use the LIKE operator. Can anyone see what I need to change to make it work on postgres?

```
def getEmployeeByName

respond_with Employee.select("id, firstname, lastname, position").where("UPPER(firstname || ' ' || lastname) LIKE ('%' || ? || '%')", params[:query])

end
```

Note, this method is an sql query written with Ruby on Rails query helpers.

Comment: `LIKE` is case sensitive in postgresql. `ILIKE` isn't.

Comment: thanks, that seems to be the problem

Comment: Also, since you're doing a case insensitive match, there's no point in doing the `UPPER(..)`. Glad to have been of help :)

Comment: I'd recommend that you stop developing on SQLite if you're deploying on top of PostgreSQL. The case sensitivity of LIKE will probably be the least of your worries. Database portability is largely a myth unless you do it manually by writing your own portability layer.

Answer (score 2):

I changed LIKE to ILIKE to make the search case insensitive.  Problem solved.