# Search model in Ruby on Rails with multiple words query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have a Ruby on Rails app, and I am trying to perform a search through a model. From the front end, I am passing the query string.

In **courses_controller.rb** I have the following code:

```
 ...
 Course.where("courses.name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
 ...
```

If params[:search] is equal to something like "marketing", it will retrieve the item with name "marketing course".
But if params[:search] is equal to "marketing course", nothing is retrieved.

How can I perform search with multiple words?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [postgres full text search like operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588717/postgres-full-text-search-like-operator)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to check the value of `params[:search]`.

Spaces in query string can be encoded with `+` or `%20` chars.

So, in this case, you're trying to find something like `marketing+course` or `marketing%20course` which doesn't exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I found a way:

```
 ...
 Course.where("courses.name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search].tr('-', ' ')}%")
 ...
```

It was adding unwanted "-" between words.